# delete content of containers.Map

Tags: matlab

is there any way to delete all the content of `container.Map` (except use remove for every key)? and use the Map again..

I tried to put 0: `MyMap = 0` but I couldn't use `MyMap` again after that command.

thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You remove all the keys from the map, which translates naturally into MATLAB:

```
 remove(MyMap, keys(MyMap));
```